# "How can we" vs. "How we can?"

Tags: questions-v-relatives

What is the proper way to ask?

> How can we achieve this?

or

> How we can archive this?

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to form a question, how/what/which etc. should be followed by a *verb*. And here, the verb is 'can'.

So,

> How *can* we achieve this?

forms a question.

Take another example.

> How we do it

is *not* forming a question. You need an *auxiliary verb* there to form a question.

> How *do* we do it?

---

I often teach my daughter in this way...

The first one is 'actually' a sentence and not a question.

> [This is] how we can achieve this!

It's not possible to mark it as a sentence with an auxiliary verb in it placed after 'how'

> [This is] how can we achieve this?

The latter requires question mark and the former does not!

Just a trick!

Comment: Then if I say `How we can do it`. What it means? Does it make sense?

Comment: In India, it's very common and if you are speaking to an Indian, it'll go 'okay!' But my personal recommendation - don't practice it!

Comment: Yes! In our country most of the people are asking/saying `How we can` instead of `How can we`. That's why got this doubt. :-) Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between these two sentences is too simple:

How can we achieve this? (This is a completed question.You are asking,what do I do? and then I achieve this)

How we can achieve this (This is not a completed question or sentence,only a phrase that describe how you do the action.)

example:
If we study hard then we can pass the exam so "this is how we can achieve the success."(Think it like "This is our method to achieve the success")